# Validation Rule issue when editing/non editing fields in a single object

Tags: formula-field

I have put a validation rule , on " Quote object" where, some fields will be non-editable( rating variables) and some can be editable ( non-rating variables) when the "Total Price" field is not zero.
Its working fine as per my below validation rule, i.e i cant change the rating varibale , its showing validation trigger message, and can able to save the non rating variables.
But now the issue is that, when sombody try to change simultaneously the rating variables, and non-rating variabes, its allowing to save ( Even if Total price is not zero), whereas ,what i need is, if simultaneously done, it shouldnt allow them to save and the validation rule should get trigger.
On below, screenshot left side is the rating variables ( shouldnt be editable , when Total Price is not zero, right are the non-rating variables, should be editable) 
[image]

[image]

My Validation Rule,

```
AND(
 PRIORVALUE(TotalPrice)!=0,
 NOT(ISCHANGED(Car_plate_number__c)),
 NOT(ISCHANGED(Car_plate_province__c)),
 NOT(ISCHANGED(Chassis_number__c)),
 NOT(ISCHANGED(Engine_number__c)),
 NOT(ISCHANGED(Finance_Company__c))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If left sided variables are the one which shouldn't be edited, then you should have included those fields in your rule instead of right sided fields.

Instead try this:

AND(
 PRIORVALUE(TotalPrice)!=0,
 (ISCHANGED(Make__c)),
 (ISCHANGED(Year_of_Manufacture__c)),
 (ISCHANGED(VehicleSumInsured__c)),
 (ISCHANGED(AdjustedVehicleSumInsured__c))
)

This says, If Total Price is not equals zero and If any of the Rating variables are changed, validation rule will be fired.

Comment: Hi Praveen, thanks. But the reason i choose to include non-rating variables is that, these are only five in the object, whereas rating variables are around 20. so it would be easier to work with only 5 fields. If you can suggest any alternatives keeping only these five non-rating variable. Thnx

Comment: If you dont include those rating variables, it will check the validation rule only with that available combination and would fire/trigger the rule accordingly.

Comment: Ya, seems true. i think i need to include those 20 fields in the validation rule. thnx